# Add a new column to a dataframe within paste0

Tags: r, dataframe

In a `for` loop in `R`, I create different dataframes and perform some operations on them. The final operation I need is to append one extra column to a dataframe with the mean values of first three columns.

My (example) code is:

```
for(comparison in c("A_N_vs_T", "A_N_vs_B", "A_N_vs_BT", "A_N_vs_Nprobes",
                    "B_N_vs_T","B_N_vs_B","B_N_vs_BT","B_N_vs_Nprobes")){
 DO SOME OPERATIONS
 assign(paste0("Norm_counts_",comparison,"$N_mean"), rowMeans(eval(parse(text=paste0("Norm_counts_",comparison)))[,c(1,2,3)],na.rm = T))
}
```

But instead of creating a new column `N_mean` it creates a new variable, called for example `Norm_counts_A_N_vs_T$N_mean`, where it stores the mean values.

Is it possible to change this behavior of `paste0`?

Thanks

Comment: I think , you should use `list` rather than using assign

Comment: Can you please examplify?

Comment: `lapply(mget(ls(pattern="Normal_counts")),function(x)transform(x,y=rowMeans(x[1:3],T)))`

Comment: This is what I got finally:
`lapply(mget(ls(pattern="Norm_counts")),function(df){
  df$N_mean <- rowMeans(df[,1:3])
  df$Treatment_mean <- rowMeans(df[,4:6])
  return(df)} )`
but why original dataframes do not change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get a character vector of the data.frames for which you want to operate on:

```
# either specify it yourself
df_names <- c("df_one", "df_two")

# or get all data.frames in the global environment
temp <- x=sapply(ls(), function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)))
df_names <- names(temp)[temp==TRUE]
```

Second, write a function that performs the operation you want.

This particular function takes in the name of a data.frame as a string and returns the data.frame (as an object) with a new column called "rowmeans" that contains the rowmeans of the first 3 columns.

```
add_rowmeans <- function(df_as_str) {
    # get the obj the str refers to
    df <- eval(as.name(df_as_str))
    # add a column with rowmeans of cols 1-3
    df$rowmeans <- rowMeans(df[,1:3])
    # return df with new column as output
    return(df)
}
```

Finally, loop over your data.frame names, applying the function to each one, and saving the result using `assign`:

```
for(i in seq_along(df_names)) {
    this_df_name <- df_names[i]
    assign(this_df_name, add_rowmeans(this_df_name))
}
```

I tested this on these 2 data.frames:

```
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 30, T), nrow=10))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 30, T), nrow=10))
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan, but if I have N dataframes, how can I apply the function for all of them? With `apply`? Sorry I am not strong in R.

Comment: Hey @Hrant - i made significant edits to my answer.  I think you'll find it much more suitable to your specific need.  Check it out.

Comment: Accepted:) Thanks for help!